# C# Como obter valor de combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox

Olá, amigos!

Estou programando em C# e uso o Visual Studio 2019 para criar um aplicativo em Forms. Tenho um combobox que eu vinculei à uma tabela usando a propriedade Datasource. Quando o usuário seleciona um valor, preciso que duas variáveis recebam os valores do DisplayMember e do ValueMember. A rotina que fiz é a seguinte:

```
private void Cb_Campo_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_Modo != 0)
    {
        Cb_Campo.DisplayMember = CampoTexto;
        Cb_Campo.ValueMember = CampoChave;
        ValorChave = int.Parse(Cb_Campo.SelectedValue.ToString());
        ValorTexto = Cb_Campo.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Por padrão, antes da seleção, o campo mostra o texto "Selecione".
Com o código acima, quando o usuário seleciona um valor da lista, a variável ValorChave recebe o valor correto, mas a variável Valortexto recebe o valor "System.Data.DataRowView". Quando troco a linha acima por...

```
ValorTexto = Cb_Campo.Text;
```

...esta variável recebe o valor "Selecione", como se nada tivesse sido selecionado.

Alguém pode me indicar o que estou fazendo de errado?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Esse resultado `System.Data.DataRowView` significa que, a propriedade `SelectedItem` te retornou **o objeto selecionado**, que foi setado no `DataSource` como você mencionou.

Para pegar um valor nesse objeto é preciso converter para  `DataRowView` e pegar o valor da coluna correta.

Na sua pergunta não tem o seu *DataSource*, mas imagine que seja uma tabela com as colunas "Codigo" e "Descricao", e nesse caso você queira recuperar o valor de "Codigo", poderia fazer assim:

```
DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)Cb_Campo.SelectedValue;
ValorChave = int.Parse(dataRowView.Row["Codigo"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A minha sugestão é você criar uma classe para guardar Chave e Valor. Depois criar uma lista de objetos dessa classe e atribuir ao DataSource da sua combo. Exemplo de código abaixo que deve funcionar no seu form.

```
public class ConteudoCombo 
{
     public int Chave {get; set;}
     public string Nome {get; set;}
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var conteudo = new List<ConteudoCombo>();
    conteudo.Add(new ConteudoCombo{Chave = 0, Nome = "SELECIONE"});
    conteudo.Add(new ConteudoCombo{Chave = 1, Nome = "OPÇÃO 1"});
    Cb_Campo.DisplayMember = nameof(ConteudoCombo.Nome);
    Cb_Campo.ValueMember = nameof(ConteudoCombo.Chave);
    Cb_Campo.DataSource = conteudo;
}

private void LerValorCombo()
{
    var conteudoSelecionado = Cb_Campo.SelectedItem as ConteudoCombo;
    ValorChave = conteudoSelecionado.Chave;
    ValorTexto = conteudoSelecionado.Nome;
}
```

Comment: Talles. Não posso fazer assim, porque o datasource já vem de uma tabela de um BD. Mas a sugestão éinteressante.

Comment: 1) Poderia editar a sua pergunta para incluir como o Cb_Campo é preenchido?

2) Já tentou essa opção? ValorTexto = Cb_Campo.SelectedText;

Comment: Olá, Talles. O que fiz foi baseado na sugestão do Ricardo (logo abaixo). Veja como ficou o trecho:                                                    
                Cb_Campo.DisplayMember = CampoTexto;
                Cb_Campo.ValueMember = CampoChave;
                ValorChave = int.Parse(Cb_Campo.SelectedValue.ToString());
                DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)Cb_Campo.SelectedItem;
                ValorTexto = dataRowView.Row[CampoTexto].ToString();